# How to show the placeholder value after clearing the text field in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder

I'm setting a text field value to empty like this

```
$("#navbarSearchField").val('');
```

now I want to re show the place holder value.
I tried triggering a foucusout and a blur but neither worked.

```
$("#navbarSearchField").trigger("blur"); // and .trigger("focusout");
```

Comment: Have you heard of [placeholder](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute in HTML?

Comment: I have a placeholder. I just want it to show when I clear the text field with jquery.

Comment: Placeholders actually show when the text field is empty

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it.

focus on another element outside the form

```
$("#navbarSearchField").val('');
$("#navbarHeader").first().focus();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Check this out**

```js
$("#s").blur(function()
{
   if($(this).val() == '')
     $(this).val('some text');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="some text">
```

Comment: This does not show the placeholder, it just sets the text field value with the placeholder value if the field is empty which is not what the op was asking.